# Comparing arbitrary revisions between branches using Bazaar

Tags: bazaar

Given two branches, `branchA` and `branchB`, is there a syntax for comparing arbitrary revision `X` of `branchA` with `Y` of `branchB`?

For example:

```
cd /path/to/branchA
bzr diff --new /path/to/branchB -rX
```

This will show the differences between revision `X` of `branchA` and the `HEAD` of `branchB`. Is there a syntax to compare against revision `Y` of `branchB` instead of the `HEAD`?

As a workaround I can create a new branch `branchB-Y` using `-rY` and then diff against that branch instead of `branchB`, but I would like to be able to diff directly without creating such temporary branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the path to the branch of the revision by appending a : and the path:

```
cd /path/to/branchA
bzr diff --new /path/to/branchB -rX..Y:/path/to/branchB
```

I just tried it out:

```
$ bzr diff --new ../checkout -r2..2:../checkout
=== modified file 'x'
--- x   2013-03-12 17:28:11 +0000
+++ x   2013-03-12 17:26:47 +0000
@@ -1,1 +1,1 @@
-aa
+zz
```

See [`bzr help revisionspec`](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.2.5/en/user-reference/revisionspec-help.html) for more information (it's hidden in the revno: section).

Comment: Wow. Good stuff. To improve the quality of your answer though, it would have been great if you also pointed out whereabouts this was in `bzr help revisionspec`, it's not exactly easy to find. (It's in the explanation of the `revno:` selector.) But hey thanks!

Comment: @Janos: Yeah I thought about that, will do that now :)